# How to stop and scroll inside a div automatically?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a div and inside it i want to display 3 texts one at a time. Like windows 8 metro theme. I have three divs like this :

`<div id='a'> Text 1</div>`
`<div id='b'> Text 2</div>`
`<div id='c'> Text 3</div>`

and another main div which wraps all these. I want to display one div at a time inside the wrapper without any occurrence of  the event from bottom to top and the new one slides over the other.

PS: i have seen how to do it using image and css. But i want to display the text through html not image, is there any way of doing this using jquery? Thank you.

Comment: http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/411/Super-simple-jQuery-ticker-text-slideshow

Comment: thank you Rab Nawaz, but they are using li and ul. I tried to use div instead and it did not work. Do i have to make changes in the css & js files which they have provided. and that is the exact effect i was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/rNcNA/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="content">Some content here</div>
    <div class="content hidden">Other content here</div>
    <div class="content hidden">Yet more content here</div>
</div>​
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var interval = 2000; // 2 seconds
    var contents = $('#container').find('.content');
    var index = 0;
    var display = function(index) {
        $('.content:visible').fadeOut('fast', function() { $(contents[index]).fadeIn(); });
        index += 1;
        if (index > contents.length-1) {
            index = 0;
        }
        setTimeout(function() { display(index) }, interval);
    }

    display(index);
});​
```

Comment: Thank you Cymen. I want to slide it up even more slow. I replaced `slow` for `fast` but there was not change. Thank you for answering. This was the one i was looking for.

Comment: Here is a [jsfiddle example with slow on both the fade in and out](http://jsfiddle.net/rsPNE/). You can likely use other [jQuery effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) too but you'll have to experiment to see what you like. Please accept the answer if this is what you want! Thanks

Comment: I forgot to mention you can increase `interval` to have more time between changing the content panel.

Comment: Nice. Thank you Cymen. That is perfect.